# The direction of a normal vector

Tags: vectors, orthonormal

This is from my textbook
[image]

I'm a little bit confused with the direction arrow of the normal vector, shouldn't it be the green vector?

[image]

Comment: The normal vector to a plane should be perpendicular to all of the vectors contained in the plane.  This is true of the pink vector, but not of the green vector.

Comment: Unless, @whoisit intends for the green vector to be normal to the plane, but point towards the inside the bowl of the quadratic form. In that case, this is a problem of not understanding conventions about which way normal vectors point.

Comment: Also note that the cross-product turns the linearly independent set $\{(1,0,f_x), (0,1,f_y)\}$ into a positive base of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\{(1,0,f_x), (0,1,f_y), (1,0,f_x)\times(0,1,f_y)\}$ (the cross-product preserves orientation of the basis) and therefore it has to take the direction shown in the figure and not the opposite direction

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit on that in an answer @Sak. It seems to me like this is what isn't being understood.

Comment: It seems to me, though, that the cross product takes the two tangent vectors in the "wrong" order, hence the result is in opposite the desired direction. Notice the big fat $-1$ in the third coordinate of the result! So I wonder if that is a mistake in the book.

Comment: @David K, Yep you are right, and actually the cross-product is taken in an order so that the basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the partials is negative. I too believe this is a mistake in the book.